# How to set GPIOs to be "low" on startup?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, startup, beagleboard, gpio

I want to control the expansion ports (GPIO) of an embedded device (BeagleBoard-xM). However, I found that they are set to be "high" on startup.

Is there any programming way to set them "low" on startup? I'm thinking writing a shell script running on startup, that will access GPIOs and set them "low". I tried also to find, if there is a script that sets GPIOs "high", in order to disable it, but without success.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

*BeagleBoard-xM Rev C, Angstrom Linux, kernel: 3.0.7*

Answer (score 2):

Usually, GPIOs default to high impedance (Z) on start up.  How do you know that the value is high? It might have a weak pull-up on it.

If you want them to go from Z to 0, then usually  you write the value first, then the direction (out).

Also make sure that the pull-up is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to have them low on *startup* (as early as possible), then it's not about Linux, but about your Bootloader. The GPIO settings there are easily done in 2-3 lines (I'm not sure which Bootloader you're using but:)

I wrote a script for BusyBox distro which puts a pin "low" (here 10 is the actual pin - you have to look it up, which number you need). Put this script into the `/etc/init.d/` directory, so it will be executed before login.

```
#! /bin/sh
#Pin 10
Echo 10     > /sys/class/gpio/export
Echo out    > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/direction
Echo 1  > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/value
```

And I had a script for the Bootloader AT91Bootstrap that puts a pin high

```
Const struct pio_desc gpio_values[] = 
{{„PC1“, AT91C_PIN_PC(1), 1, PIO_DEFAULT, PIO_OUTPUT}};

pio_setup(gpio_values);
```

I hope this could help you

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use this code in the gpio_init.sh file?

```
sudo sh -c "echo '10' > /sys/class/gpio/export"
sudo sh -c "echo 'out' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/direction"
sudo sh -c "echo '1' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/value"
```